# BluetoothSocket.connect doesn't throw an exception, but I'm not connected

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Try to connect with Bluetooth SPP to an ESP-32. Below is my code for the connect method in Android Studio.

```
private fun bluetoothConnect() {
    var address : String? = null
    var uuids : Array<ParcelUuid>? = null
    val pairedDevices : Set<BluetoothDevice> = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()
    for (item in pairedDevices) {
        if(item.name == "Test"){
            address = item.address
            uuids = item.uuids
        }
    }

    val uuid : UUID? = uuids?.get(0)?.uuid
    Log.d("Bluetooth", "UUID: "+uuid.toString())
    try {
        bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)
        socket = device?.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
        socket?.connect()
    } catch (e : IOException) {
        Log.e("Bluetooth", "Connection failed")
    }

    if (socket?.isConnected == true) {
        Log.i("Bluetooth", "Success")
    } else {
        Log.e("Bluetooth", "Fail")
    }
}
```

1. Not seeing any sort of connection attempt on my ESP monitor
2. I'm able to connect with a Bluetooth SPP Manager from the Play Store
3. There are no errors being thrown except the "Fail" error at the end of the code chunk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new to Kotlin and Android programming so please forgive me if this code is hard to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the first line in the try with this.

```
device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)
```

Source: I'm the OP, and this fixed it